# Subtotal count of records is coming wrong in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, report

I'm using jasper reports to generate the status of all records, Like Active, cancelled, expired and pending. I classified the list of records in categories and each category displays the total count of records.

Suppose In category 1: there are 10 records, Active:5, Cancelled:3 and Pending:2.
In category 2: there are 8 records, Active:2, Cancelled:5 and Pending:1.
In category 3: there are 17 records, Active:12, Cancelled: and Pending:5.

In result,
The pending count total for category  it displays as 2. **This is correct**

But the pending count total for category 2 it displays as 3 (category 1: count 2 and category 2: count 1), Whereas it should have got reset and displayed only 1.

similarly for category 3 it displays pending total count as 8 (2+1+5 pending) instead of 5.

I have used resetType="Group" resetGroup="xyz" calculation="Count" in variable tag

How can i get the pending count correct? I get other active and cancelled count correctly

Comment: if you include the relative jrxml we will have a look some problem with resetGroup...

Comment: In <group name="xyz">
I have this textField and
Inside textField tag, I'm using
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{pending_count}]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: This is not the problem,  the resetGroup defines how to reset the count... need your .jrxml to be able to help you, variable expression value?

Comment: I wont be able to share the whole .jrxml at this moment. Could you tell me where is the reset feature written?